# Looping through XML file elements

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a XML file below. I want to loop through this file and extract the node node value, like for node `<com>` get the name value and then loop 2 times to get the file values. I can currently get the value for the node `<com>` but am unsure how to loop inside and get the values for file node.

```xml
<common>
  <com name="Test1.css">
    <file name="Tech.css"/>
    <file name="Comp.css"/> 
  </com>
  <com name="Test2.css">
    <file name="HR.css"/>
    <file name="HR2.css"/> 
  </com> 
</common>
```

```vb
Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, plot
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("C:\test\combineXML.xml")
WScript.Echo xmlDoc.parseError
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("com")
If objNodeList.length > 0 then
    For each x in objNodeList
        JobName = x.getattribute("name")
        WScript.Echo JobName
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.ChildNodes` Property

```
Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, plot
dim fileNodes
dim comNodeItem
dim fileNodeItem
dim fileName, jobName

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("C:\test\combineXML.xml")

WScript.Echo xmlDoc.parseError

Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("com")

For each comNodeItem in objNodeList
    JobName = comNodeItem.getAttribute("name")
    for each fileNodeItem in comNodeItem.ChildNodes
        fileName = fileNodeItem.getAttribute("name")
        WScript.Echo JobName & ": " & fileName
    next
Next
```

This will work if the file is as simple as your example. If you want only `file` nodes to be processed, and others ignored, you can also just use again:

```
    for each fileNodeItem in comNodeItem.getElementsByTagName("file")
```

Answer (score 5):

You're making this too complicated. Just select the `name` attribute from the child nodes of all `com` nodes with an XPath expression:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.load "C:\test\combineXML.xml"
If xmlDoc.parseError = 0 Then
  For Each x In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//com/*/@name")
    WScript.Echo x.text
  Next
End If
```

Use `//com/file/@name` if you need the expression to be more specific (in case there are other child nodes with a `name` attribute.

If you also want attributes from a parent node, you'll have to modify it like this:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.load "C:\test\combineXML.xml"
If xmlDoc.parseError = 0 Then
  For Each x In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//com/*")
    WScript.Echo x.parentNode.getAttribute("name") & ": " _
      & x.getAttribute("name")
  Next
End If
```

Comment: Very nice..how can I also get the values of the com node ..like I want the result like this  test1 tech.css comp.css and then test2.css HR.css HR2.css